# get IP address but in xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx format in Android

Tags: android

Hi guys I've gone through a lot of coding on line to get my android mobiles IP address
Most of them are ending with

```
if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress())
                { return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString();     }
```

How ever i get something that looks like this:- "fe80::a00:27ff:fe37:28b5%eth1"
Weird cause I was expecting something like xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Can some one help me understand whats this?

Comment: see question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11015912/how-do-i-get-ip-address-in-ipv4-format

Comment: Yes.   That makes sense now. 1 last thing.

Answer (score 2):

That is an IPv6 address. Additionally, since it starts with `fe80::` you know it's also a [link-local IPv6 address](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4291#section-2.5.6), so cannot be used for communication beyond the local network. (in this case, `eth1`, since that is the scope specified at the end after the `%` - but note that using a `%` to identify the scope isn't always valid when using an IPv6 address.)

Comment: Great! Now here's what I did- I got this Ipv6 address of my phone (server) and placed it in my Emulator (client), but it failed to connect. Then I did it the old fashion way xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx format and it connected! So any way I could directly get the old format as this Ipv6 isnt working any ways?

Comment: @Wadia, there are a number of possible approaches to filter out the unwanted IPv6 addresses (see the other answers to this question). One approach I saw was to check if a `:` exists in the address. If so, it's an IPv6 address.

Answer (score 1):

Try `java.net.Inet4Address` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Its returning IPV6 address.

Check if its IPV4 address before returning result.

```
if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress() && inetAddress instanceof Inet4Address) {
    return inetAddress.getHostAddress().toString(); 
}
```

Hope this helps.